# Javascript encoding problem when downloading files

Tags: javascript, batch-file, command-line, character-encoding

I have a page which converts images to ANSI colored batch console art, with a download button, but it gives errors when I open it. In notepad I noticed it says "**Unix (LF)**" on the bottom right corner. All my other batch scripts are "**Windows (CRLF)**". How can I encode it to the correct format? Is that the problem?

example from the batch (one pixel is one █ character, ESC is the ANSI escape character):

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
cls

echo ESC[38;2;21;20;26m█ESC[38;2;21;20;26m█

...

pause >nul
```

[image]

Those are the errors.
It works perfectly when I paste the code into a new .bat file so it's definitely some sort of encoding problem.

The js that handles the download:

```js
var dwn = $('#download') // Download button

dwn.download = 'console-img.bat'
dwn.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result], { type: 'text/plain' }))

// result is a string containing the code
```

Comment: Very likely. Whereas Notepad now detects which line-termination character-sequence is in use for the file loaded, there appears to be no way to tell it to convert to another. The easy way is to give away Notepad and use a real editor like `editplus` or `notepad++` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a bit of researching about CRLF / LF I found the solution.

Replace all the `\n` in your string to `\r\n`